# Write a permutation as a product of permutations of a given subset

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, algebra-precalculus, graph-theory, permutations

I've been given this problem :

> Let $G\subset \mathcal{S}_n$ and $\sigma \in \langle G\rangle$. We call minimal product of $\sigma$ the data of an integer $i$ and an array $(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_i)$ verifying
> \begin{align} &\bullet \forall 1\leq k\leq i, \sigma_k \in G\\
> &\bullet \sigma_1...\sigma_i = \sigma\\
> &\bullet \forall j<i, \text{there isn't any array } (\sigma_1',...,\sigma_j') \in G^j \text{ such that } \sigma_1'...\sigma_j'=\sigma \end{align}
> You are asked to provide an efficient way to provide a minimal product of $\sigma$

One can be convinced that any $\sigma \in \langle G\rangle$ can be reached by a finite product of permutations of $G$, thus a minimal product exists
Yet i didn't find any promising approach, introducing a graph isn't a bad idea I believe.

Comment: I don't believe that there is an efficient way to solve this in general. The Rubik's cube group is an example of this problem with $n=48$, and solving that required huge amounts of computing power.

Comment: I guess you're looking at a subset $G$ of the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) $\mathcal S_n$ and the group $\langle G\rangle$ [generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) by $G$, right? Finally, what do you mean by efficient way?